# Data manipulation for anychart.stepLine()

Tags: javascript, anychart

I created `anychart.stepLine()`. I want to streaming data. Now I can do this but I have to delete the last series (otherwise I have drawn many series). 
I want to added new data and draw the missing piece - not draw a new chart.

This is my code: data - array with start data, allData - array with data which I want to added to click button

```
var chart = anychart.stepLine();
var series = chart.stepLine(data);
series.stepDirection("forward");

function startStream() {
  var myVar =  setInterval( function() {
    var index = searchIndex(allData,data[data.length-1][0]);
    for (var i = index; i < index + 3; i++) {
      console.log(data.length)
      if (i < allData.length) {
        data.push(allData[i]);
        chart.removeSeriesAt(chart.getSeriesCount()-1)
        chart.stepLine(data)
      } else {
        console.log("Koniec allData");
        clearInterval(myVar);
      }
    }
  }, 800);
}

function searchIndex(array, item) {
  for (var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i][0] == item ) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change  `chart.removeSeriesAt(chart.getSeriesCount()-1)` from a something like t`able.add(newData)` - but `series.addData` doesn't works and change `chart.removeSeriesAt(chart.getSeriesCount()-1)` to `chart.series(newData)` - draw a new series.

Is it possible draw a missing piece? Or it's a the best solution my goals?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the Cartesian chart with stepLine series you can add new points to the series using [append()](https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Data_Manipulation#add) method point by point.
If you will use a Stock chart with stepLine series you will have more abilities with the data table. It supports [addData()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.data.Table#addData) method and you will be able to add multiple new points by one method call.